# WebView redraw problem when loading data

Tags: android, android-webview

I encounter a problem of display with a webview i'm using in one of my application.

When I call loadData, the webview first display the text and then load the images of the page (standard behaviour).

Sometimes, if those images modify the text position, the old text position is not cleared and both old text and new text+image is displayed

Here a screenshot of what it looks like when the problem occurs:

[image: webview redraw problem]

It's like the webview do not redraw correctly it's content. Of course a simple invalidate() does not work...

It do no occur often but lets say one time over 20.

Code used to display the data (called outside Activity life cycle methods):

```
// Include the html headers to the content received from WS
String webtext = String.format(ConfigApp.HTML_BODY, wsdata.getText());
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(...);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(...);
mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, webtext, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Without seeing the `html` data you are attempting to load, we cannot help solve this problem (as it may very well be your `html`, not `Android`.

Comment: I cannot come from the HTML. It displays correctly most of the times on the phone and there is no problem on firefox. It seems a refresh/redraw problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've finally found a way to fix the problem.

Remove the WebView transparent background:

```
String webtext = String.format(ConfigApp.HTML_BODY, wsdata.getText());
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(...);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(...);
// mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, webtext, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Because my WebView has a blank background it's ok for me. Maybe it can be annoying for somebody else.

For sure it's a WebView bug.

Comment: So what I supposed to do if I need transparent webview... :(

Comment: Unfortunately, no idea. There is no issues on the android bug tracker for this particular problem. Maybe you should fill one.

Comment: @Roman Truba: i had the same problem, i needed my webview transparent to be displayed the same color as my parent Viewgroup background.With luck, this parent background had just one color, so i use this color for my webview background and it fixed the bug.

Comment: @VinceFR , i had an image in background. I had to insert this image in html, it was very ugly

Comment: Does anyone have an idea about which version this occurs on? I've met this bug while using an emulator running v2.3.4., I'm pretty sure it won't happen on ICS or newer.

Comment: I no longer see this on 4.2.2 or 4.3. For me it appears on AOKP version of 4.0.4 on my HTC Desire.

Answer (score 1):

If you set your `WebView` to a specific size, and not `"wrap_content"` , then after the data is loaded, the webview doesn't resize its content correctly.

I think it's a bug with the widget..

So..
Try to use  `"wrap_content"` in the `layout_height` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I have frequently had sporadic problems with WebViews not displaying properly after having loaded content with loadDataWithBaseUrl.   Although the WebView's height was set to wrap_content, the WebView wouldn't always resize to wrap the content.   Instead the webview had a height of zero.  Sometimes it would display fine and other times it would not.   Sometimes the problem would only happen in a portrait orientation and landscape would work fine.   I tried removing my setBackgroundColor call but that it did not help.  However, I was able to get the problem to go away today by changing the layout that the WebView was in from a LinearLayout to a RelativeLayout.

Comment: thanks for sharing your experience. I will your solution next time I face WebView problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00ff0000);
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read the [How to Answer a Question Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). This site is a Q&A site not a forum. Can you please add some more details?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call **refreshDrawableState()** method after calling **loadDataWithBaseURL()** method 
and its will resolve your problem

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, webtext, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
mWebView.refreshDrawableState();
```